# Django, files загрузка и обработка

Tags: python, django

Вопрос может быть тривиальный но  гугл не очень помог.

Юзер загружает файл в формате **.txt** , и должно выдать в формате **pdf**,
З загрузкой все понятно, да и з обработкой в формат **pdf** так же разберусь.

Только обясните как зделать, когда файл обработало в формат **pdf**, что бы автоматически выдавало возможность скачать этот файл для юзера.

Comment: А в чём именно проблема? Если у вас уже будет готовый файл, то дать пользователю ссылку на него - задача тривиальная. Что у вас не получается?

Comment: Вот именно и в этом проблема, не до конца понимаю как дать эту сылку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Настройте раздачу статических файлов, кладите ваши pdf в папку со статикой, и выдавайте пользователю ссылку, которая будет склеена из адреса папки со статикой + имени самого файла.